# Green play icon has disappeared after fresh install

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have recently changed my computer and now that I have reinstalled everything (including Miniconda3 and VSCode), I don't understand why the green play icon (top right corner) is gone. Right-clicking in the editor gets me the option of running current code in terminal, so the interpreter is linked right, but no green play icon.

Am I missing something? Do I need to do something particular in order to get that simple button back?

Comment: is the button gone or grey? If you create a `launch.json` from the Run/Debug bar does it get back, that button is linked with the presence of a launch config

Comment: In the debug section, the button is still there and green and it works. Before I had a similar button in the top-right corner of the window, besides the Split Editor button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was actually the version. My organization had an old version in its software center, I had to get IT manually update my VSCode to the last version (1.51.1) and everything is fine.